# Is there any cancel operation method in install4j api using which one can exit the installation process?

Tags: install4j

I want to cancel the installation process programetically. Is there any method available in the install4j api for it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of install4j 6.0.4, there is no such method. The only way to cancel programmatically, is to add a "Run script" action with the "Script" property set to

```
return false;
```

and the "Failure strategy" property set to "Quit on failure. The action itself can have a "Condition expression" so you can determine elsewhere whether or not to cancel.